# Insert null value into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this code

```
public void insertAssignment(long mediaEvent_ID, long mediaBranch_ID,
int? isPremiere, int? isNew, int? isLastChance, 
int? isPrevShown, int season_ID, int? audio_ID, 
int? video_ID, DateTime startdate)
{
    query = "insert into Assignment Values(" + mediaEvent_ID+ "," 
    + mediaBranch_ID + "," + isPremiere + "," + isNew + "," 
    + isLastChance + "," + isPrevShown
    + "," + season_ID + "," + audio_ID + "," + video_ID + ",'" +  
    startdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ")";   }
```

I have a problem while insert if any attribute is null like `isPremiere=null` problem 
is `insert {values(mediaEvent,mediaBranch,(is empty not contains a values ),......)}`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: please clarify your question's english

Comment: May be you are saying that if any of the value is null then your insert fails. Is it that? Then in that case, check whether your DB tables accepts null against that particular column or not.

Comment: my DB Tables accept null values

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were writing a tsql with literals, you would need to detect the null scenario and append "null" rather than the value, so the SQL looks like

```
1,2,null,4,5
```

If you see what I mean. However, this is a bad way to do it - your SQL right now is really really dangerous. You should parameterize instead - this solves a range of problems:

- sql injection(your code is a security risk right now)
- formatting (dates etc)
- null values
- query plan reuse (or the lack of it)

For example:

```
query = "insert into Assignment Values(@eventId, @branchId, @isPremiere, @isNew, ...)"
```

where you add a parameter with value for each of the placeholders. Note that due to how ado.net you need to represent nulls with DBNull:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo",
    foo == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)foo);
```

(For each parameter)

Note that orms and micro-orms will help make this simple. For example with dapper:

```
DateTime foo = ...
int? bar = ...
connection.Execute(
     @"insert ... values (@foo, @bar)",
    new { foo, bar });
```

Comment: Nice answer. Btw, are you sure that query plan wouldn't be reused?

Comment: @lazy if you concatenate raw values into the SQL, then most times the commands will be different (different hashes etc) - so if you don't parameterize, you certainly won't get the type of query plan reuse you usually want. Am I answering the right question there?

Comment: I'm just qualifying whether some kind of automatic query parametrization can occur in SQL server. I know it can automatically parametrize where clauses of select statements. Who knows - maybe it is smart enough to do same with inserts :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem below style

```
string sql= insert into Table(limit) values("+TBkapidaMinLimit.Text==""?"null":TBkapidaMinLimit.Text)+")"
```